# springmvc with velocity:Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I run a springmvc and velocity demo and meet the problem that Could not resolve view with name 'index'(controll to index.vm) and below is my project configuration:

```html
└─WEB-INF
    │  applicationContent-servlet.xml
    │  velocity.properties
    │  web.xml
    │
    ├─fragments
    │    _footer.vm
    │    _header.vm
    │
    ├─layouts
    │    layout.vm
    │
    └─views
         index.vm
```

below is my velocity configuration in applicationContext-servlet.xml

```html
   <bean id="velocityConfig"  
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">  
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />  
        <property name="velocityProperties">      
        <props>      
            <prop  key="input.encoding">UTF-8</prop>      
            <prop  key="output.encoding">UTF-8</prop>        
         </props>      
     </property>   
    </bean>  
  
    <bean id="viewResolver"  
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">  
        <property name="cache" value="true" />  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />  
        <property name="layoutUrl" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/layout.vm" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />  
        <property name="contentType"><value>text/html;charset=UTF-8</value></property>    
    </bean>
```

and below is my web.xml

```html
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param> 
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
           <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet.xml 
           </param-value> 
          </init-param> 
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

my controll code is like that:

```html
@Controller
public class ArticleController {

 @Autowired
 private ArticleService articleService;

 @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String welcomePage(Model model) {
  List<Article> list = articleService.getArticles();
  model.addAttribute("departments", list);
  return "index";
 }
}
```

when I run on tomcat I meet the problem that can't reach index.vm,is there any thing wrong in xml configuration ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In applicationContext-servlet.xml change

```
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
```

to

```
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/views/" />
```

Comment: sorry,I post the wrong file path,there is velocity folder

Answer (score 0):

I changed

`<property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />`

to

`<property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/" />`

adn it works